# bxslider minimal template causes one slide to be skipped

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I have the most bare bones bxslider template I can think of and I am having a bug where the second slide is skipped when hitting the right arrow. The bug happens in Chrome + Firefox. I am using the latest version available. You will notice that "3" displays when hitting the next arrow.

I have to be doing something fundamentally wrong, but I cannot figure it out.

HERE IS A LIVE DEMO:
http://blastohosting.com/bxslider_bug/

CODE:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.bxslider.css">

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#features").bxSlider();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="features">
    <div class="feature">
        1
    </div>

    <div class="feature">
        2
    </div>

    <div class="feature">
        3
    </div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `<ul>` as per their example as some of the styling that is applied is `<li>` specific. It also works much better when there are images or content to push the height out.

Check my fiddles:

With images: http://jsfiddle.net/e4RLH/

With 1,2,3: http://jsfiddle.net/e4RLH/2/

Comment: I figured out the problem, I downgraded jquery to 1.8.2 (I was using 1.11.0) and it worked as expected. I opened a ticket at https://github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider-4/issues/459

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, I downgraded jquery to 1.8.2 (I was using 1.11.0) and it worked as expected. I opened a ticket at github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider-4/issues/459